# Hibernate: Joining across join tables on a non-primary key (but that is part of one)

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to map a legacy database that has some fairly interesting join scenarios. I'm specifically attempting to join across a join table to a non-primary key. Right now, I am getting an error that states that the reference is not mapped to a single property

### Database

First up is the database, which has been simplified greatly for this question. There are three tables that are of interest:
[image: Database relationship diagram]

The **User** table contains the main data and includes a column, 'ReferenceId'. The **Location** table is similar in that it has a 'ReferenceId' as well, and represents the data that I would like to embed into the User at the end of the day. This table is notable because it a) has a compound key and b) The column I am trying to join on is part of this key. Finally, **UserLocation** is the table that ties them together, having a mapping of referenceIds to ReferenceIds.

### Classes

Now to map them together. I have my classes:

**User**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3709178675764332063L;

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "uname")
    private Long name;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Location.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "CandidateLocation", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "UserReference") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "LocationReference", referencedColumnName="ReferenceId") })
    private Location location;

}
```

and Location:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Locations")
@IdClass(LocationPK.class)
public class Location implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -582319915736694876L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "referenceId")
    private Long referenceId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "IDParam1")
    private Long IDParam1;

    @Column(name = "loc_name")
    private String name;


    // ETC... 
}
```

### Problem

The problem that I am getting is that the association does not work. Instead, I get an exception that looks like:

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(ReferenceId)
>   of com.foo.User.location referencing com.foo.Location not mapped to a
>   single property.

I can't omit the `referenceColumnName` or it will default to the PK, but other than that, I'm at a bit of a loss. Hopefully I am missing something that is obvious to others. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the join table, you say that the referenced column name is "ReferenceId", and in the Location entity, the reference field is mapped to a column named "reference". Moreover, why use a composite ID in Location if the reference is sufficient to uniquely identify a Location? And if it's not sufficient, how can you have a OneToOne association?

Comment: Thanks for the catch on the 'ReferenceId' vs 'Reference' mismatch. The mappings should be consistently 'ReferenceId'. I've corrected this in the example. There is a one-to-one relationship with respect to the particular user, but it is not unique to the 'Location' table. Ultimately this may be a many-to-one relationship, and I've tried this too with the same Exception being thrown.

Comment: Maybe change the R to lowercase in referencedColumnName="ReferenceId" to match. Probably this shouldn't matter ...